# android:layout_weight for View behaves the opposite from what is expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to distribute weights in LinearLayout.
While it works with ButtonView-s, it just works the opposite for simple View:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#00FF00" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#0000FF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

and

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#00FF00" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#0000FF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

It is deffinetly implementation of ButtonView that makes it work correctly.
But what should be implemented (and how) in a View to be consistent with LinearLayout behavior?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Same output for both, re-check.

Comment: same output for me too.

Comment: Yes, indeed - it is wrong for my my custom View though (

Comment: @user1986565 What are you trying to ask and achieve in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace "View" by "FrameLayout" I don't think that View is expected to be used as a holder

Comment: May be so. What if I want to implement my custom view and extend the View? What should be implemented in a View to be consistent with LinearLayout behavior? I understant it is onMeasure(). But how?
I already did that, but it does not work with weights.

Answer (score 0):

After being frustrated by the same problem, I ended up using a `TextView` with no text.

I've only seen this problem in **Eclipse's graphical layout mode**.  On my Galaxy S2, the app works as expected.

Playing around with the `layout_weight` of the raw "View" does produce really weird effects.

Another work-around is changing the `layout_height` of the `View` from `"0dp"` to `"1dp"`.  I don't know why that fixes it, but I'm guessing some deep magic (i.e. a bug, perhaps a magical tapeworm) related to zero.